# Can't set on overided library class for the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, storyboard

I have a storyboard controller with a class and the `.m` file of this class is in the library `.a` so  I need to override some methods of this class. The `.h` file is:

```
@interface AxSimpleAppealSendController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) AxSimpleAppealSendObject * object;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showInModal;
@end
```

What I did: 
I create the inherited class: `.h`

```
#import "AxSimpleAppealSendController.h"
@interface CustomAppealSendController : AxSimpleAppealSendController
@property (nonatomic, retain) AxSimpleAppealSendObject * object;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showInModal;
@end
```

`.m`

```
#import "CustomAppealSendController.h"   
@implementation CustomAppealSendController
@end
```

and set this new class as the storyboard class for my controller, but when I try to open this view controller in my app - I got exception:

```
'-[UITableViewController setObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcbd1340'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't forget to make **clean** of your project after this actions!